# camera overlay picture

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

**edit 3**

Good news and bad news. The good news is that in the Connections Inspector by disconnecting the overlay UIToolbar and connecting the UIImageview, I see `theKing`, but then -- the bad news -- I do not see the UIToolbar, which I also need. So the question now is, how can the user get back to the calling VC when s/he is finished here? How can both the toolbar and the image be part of the the overlay, or can the "go back button" toolbar be on the non-overlay view, or something? Or how can I make both the toolbar and the image show on the OverlayViewController?

**edit 3**

**edit 2**

`setupImagePicker` in `OverlayViewController.m`.

```
- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        // user wants to use the camera interface
        //
        self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

        if ([[self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView subviews] count] == 0)
        {
            // setup our custom overlay view for the camera
            //
            // ensure that our custom view's frame fits within the parent frame
            CGRect overlayViewFrame = self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                         CGRectGetHeight(overlayViewFrame) -
                                         self.view.frame.size.height - 10.0,
                                         CGRectGetWidth(overlayViewFrame),
                                         self.view.frame.size.height + 10.0);
            self.view.frame = newFrame;
            [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];
        }
    }
}
```

**edit 2**

**edit 1**

[This is the PhotoPicker sample code link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/PhotoPicker.zip).

**edit 1**

**edit 0**

Has anyone tried this on an iPhone instead of an iPad? I do not have an iPhone, but I was reading Matt Neuburg's book today where he says UIImagePicker works differently on the 2 devices.

**edit 0**

I cannot see the image I am attempting to overlay across the camera view in UIImagePicker. No matter how I add the IBOutlet, as a property or not, the image does not show, but the overlayed toolbar shows fine. Why?

OverlayViewController.h  with `theKing` IBOutlet added to Apple's sample code and then commented out for now.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@protocol OverlayViewControllerDelegate;

@interface OverlayViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    // IBOutlet UIImageView* theKing;   ******** temporarily commented out
    id <OverlayViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}    

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <OverlayViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;

- (void)setupImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType;

@end

@protocol OverlayViewControllerDelegate
- (void)didTakePicture:(UIImage *)picture;
- (void)didFinishWithCamera;
@end
```

OverlayViewController.m with the `property` for `theKing` IBOutlet added to Apple's sample code.

```
#import "OverlayViewController.h"

enum
{
    kOneShot,       // user wants to take a delayed single shot
    kRepeatingShot  // user wants to take repeating shots
};

@interface OverlayViewController ( )

@property (assign) SystemSoundID tickSound;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* theKing;  // added *********
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *takePictureButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *startStopButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *timedButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *tickTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *cameraTimer;
```

I cannot see the image `theKing` when I execute the code on an iPhone. Below is a view of the nib I have added showing some of the connections made. No errors are thrown, but I cannot see the image, only the UIToolbar already added.

[image: nib of overlay controller]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

I've updated it now and tried to replicate what you've done in your question. I've included full source of .h/.m and `theKing@2x.png`. Create a new project and paste the source into the files and add `theKing@2x.png`. Everything is done programmatically - you don't need to set anything up in interface builder other than embedding your view in a navigation controller.

Here is `theKing@2x.png` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDcoo.png

#### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> 

@end
```

#### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // assign action to button
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 60);
    myButton.center = self.view.center;
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myButton setTitle:@"Image Picker" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}

- (void)buttonPress:(id)sender {
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        // alert the user that the camera can't be accessed
        UIAlertView *noCameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Camera" message:@"Unable to access the camera!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [noCameraAlert show];

    } else {

        // prepare imagePicker view
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;

        // create view for overlay
        CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imagePicker.view.frame.size.width, imagePicker.view.frame.size.height);
        UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayRect];

        // prepare the image to overlay
        UIImageView *overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"theKing"]];
        overlayImage.center = overlayView.center;
        overlayImage.alpha = 0.5;

        // prepare toolbar for overlay
        UIToolbar *overlayToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 600, overlayView.frame.size.width, 40)];
        overlayToolbar.center = CGPointMake(overlayView.center.x, overlayView.frame.size.height - 20);
        overlayToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

        UIBarButtonItem *takePictureButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(takePictureButtonPressed:)];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleBarSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        flexibleBarSpace.width = 1000;
        UIBarButtonItem *startStopButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Snap" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(startStopButtonPressed:)];
        UIBarButtonItem *timedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Timed" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action: @selector(timedButtonPressed:)];
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action: @selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];

        overlayToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:takePictureButton, flexibleBarSpace, startStopButton, timedButton, cancelButton, nil];


        [overlayView addSubview:overlayImage];
        [overlayView addSubview:overlayToolbar];

        // add the image as the overlay
        [imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];

        // display imagePicker
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIBarButton Selectors

- (void)takePictureButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"takePictureButtonPressed...");
    // TODO: take picture!
}

- (void)startStopButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"startStopButtonPressed...");
    // TODO: make this do something
}

- (void)timedButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"timedButtonPressed...");
    // TODO: implement timer before calling takePictureButtonPressed
}

- (void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"cancelButtonPressed");
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerController Delegate Methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    // determine if the user selected or took a new photo
    UIImage *selectedImage;
    if ([editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]) selectedImage = (UIImage *)[editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    else if ([editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]) selectedImage = (UIImage *)[editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    // TODO: Do something with selectedImage (put it in a UIImageView

    // dismiss the imagePicker
    [picker.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

#### Screenshot

This is what it looks like when I run it.
[image: Screenshot]

Does this satisfy your app requirements?

Comment: Sorry to have taken so long to reply. So far I have only encountered an error that "No known class for selector `setCameraOverlayView`", and due to other obligations I cannot research that issue. Could you look at `setupImagePicker:` in `-OverlayViewController.m` ? I'll add it to the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you zip and post your source?  I can take a look tonight.  I'll be AFK for the majority of the day today, but when I get back home tonight I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I don't think I can get to my computer until Sunday night. I'll zip and send to you then. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any free places to place zip files like dpaste.com for source files. I have a github account, but don't know how to use it for storing an isolated zip file and am very unfamiliar with the whole github approach. Is there a way to share files via SO?

Comment: [Can you try to get the file `setup.zip` at ](http://schott.selfip.net/~brian/), please? I don't know if I have really done this correctly so please give feedback about the accessibility of the link and file.

Comment: Got the file... will have a look shortly.

Comment: Apologies for delay.  You forgot to include `BSsetupOverlayViewController.xib` in the zip.

Comment: I have now added it, unzipped to the link. I now notice that it is listed in the xcode file list like the other files, but it has sort of appended graphic `A` character, while other files have no characters appended. Could that be the problem -- that it was not available to the project?  The copy I retrieved is actually from the real xcode project I am working on, not this test project. But the nib shows up in the `setup` project, too. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Wait. I had placed the wrong zip file into that link. Please use the following zip file instead at the link. `PhotoPicker-1.zip` Sorry for the goof up.

Comment: I tried implementing your edited answer in the `OverlayViewController` class in the `-setupImagePicker:` method, replacing your `yourImagePickerController` with `self.view` but got warnings that `overlayView` may not be recognized and then an exception was thrown over that issue. I am sorry you could not follow my edits; I finally concluded that the overlay view would not take both an image and a button (or something like a button) so I just put the image in a button. See (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857228/), please. And thanks, a lot.

Comment: You're correct that the `overlayView` won't take two different Views.  Since `overlayView` is looking for a `UIView`, I thought it'd be best to create a `UIView` then add two subviews (a `UIImage` and `UIToolbar`) and assign that `UIView` as the `overlayView` for your `UIImagePickerController`.  I should've been more clear about that.  In any case, glad you've got your issue sorted out!

Comment: I would really like to do it your way. Can you be more specific about where your code is placed and exactly what I replace `yourImagePickerController` with in your code. Does your code belong in `-setupImagePicker:` in `OverlayViewController`, or in `-viewDidLoad` in `MyViewController`, for example? I have tried various placements and substitutions, but cannot quite get it right.

Comment: I've updated it now and tried to replicate what you've done in your question.  I've included full source of .h/.m and `theKing@2x.png`.  Create a new project and paste this code in.  Everything is done programmatically - you don't need to set anything up in interface builder.  Has this satisfied your question?

Comment: That's great. I finally got yours working. I would like for there NOT to have the `Image Picker` button, but instead to go directly to the preview window, and I would like the toolbar at the bottom to have only one button, `Done`. At present I must use the `Cancel` button. I think even I can change the `Cancel` to `Done` and eliminate the other buttons from the toolbar. Another thing I could use help with is forcing the Front camera to be used instead of the Rear camera. I am researching that. Thanks for your persistence. Can you help me to remove the initial `Image Picker` button stage?

Comment: I have fixed the `Cancel` button toolbar and have forced the Front camera, myself. Now I'll work on removing the `Image Picker` button and its stage.

Comment: Remove the button?  Delete the button related code in `viewDidLoad` then move the code from `buttonPress` to `viewDidLoad`.  Alternatively, you could also just call `buttonPress` using `[self buttonPress:self]` in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 3):

One answer I have found is to put the image on a huge button which has as an action `Done:`. I'll have to figure out a way to tell my user to do it, but at least this will dismiss the image view and finish my setup mode. I would really like a cleaner alternative, so please add answers if you have them. Thanks to all who have considered my question.